# Bulk Upload/Import of JSON files to Azure Cosmos DB from Java Code

Tags: java, json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm generating a `JSON` file in `JAVA`. The file contains a list of `JSONs`. I want to import this file to `Azure Cosmos DB` as soon as it is created.

Is there some way to achieve it from Java code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I knew, we can use [bulk executor Java library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-bulkexecutor-java-getting-started) to implement bulk operations. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-java

Comment: Thanks Jim for your response. This library seems very complex to use. I was just looking for a simpler workaround just like in .NET, it hardly took 10-12 lines to achieve the purpose and it was easily understandable. If nothing simpler is there, then surely I would have to use this.

Comment: I'm not able to do this. Is it possible for you to help me out?

Comment: I agree bulk import is complicated. I eventually gave up and used a data factory pipleline which is a much nicer experience. Also, now that autopilot is available in CosmosDB the throughput throttling is no longer an issue. Feels like CosmosDB has a few rough edges.

Comment: @aar-01 I have updated my answer, please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research,  if we want to implement bulk operations with java, we just can use bulk executor Java library. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-java) and [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-bulk-executor-java). Regarding how to use bulk executor Java library, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-java).

For example

1. My `.json` file

```
[{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "test1",
        "age": "20"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "test2",
        "age": "21"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "test3",
        "age": "22"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "test4",
        "age": "23"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "test5",
        "age": "24"
    }, {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "test6",
        "age": "25"
    }, {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "test7",
        "age": "26"
    }, {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "test8",
        "age": "27"
    }
]
```

2. My `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>documentdb-bulkexecutor</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

3. Code

```
 String endpoint="<your cosmos db endpoint>";
        String key="<your key>";
        ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy();
        connectionPolicy.setMaxPoolSize(1000);
        DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(
                endpoint,
                key,
                connectionPolicy,
                ConsistencyLevel.Session);
        String databaseId="testbulk";
        String collectionId="items";
        String databaseLink = String.format("/dbs/%s", databaseId);
        String collectionLink = String.format("/dbs/%s/colls/%s", "testbulk", collectionId);

        ResourceResponse<Database> databaseResponse = null;
        Database readDatabase = null;
        try {
            databaseResponse = client.readDatabase(databaseLink, null);
            readDatabase = databaseResponse.getResource();

            System.out.println("Database already exists...");

        } catch (DocumentClientException dce) {
            if (dce.getStatusCode() == 404) {
                System.out.println("Attempting to create database since non-existent...");

                Database databaseDefinition = new Database();
                databaseDefinition.setId(databaseId);


                    client.createDatabase(databaseDefinition, null);


                databaseResponse = client.readDatabase(databaseLink, null);
                readDatabase = databaseResponse.getResource();
            } else {
                throw dce;
            }
        }

        ResourceResponse<DocumentCollection> collectionResponse = null;
        DocumentCollection readCollection = null;

        try {
            collectionResponse = client.readCollection(collectionLink, null);
            readCollection = collectionResponse.getResource();

            System.out.println("Collection already exists...");
        } catch (DocumentClientException dce) {
            if (dce.getStatusCode() == 404) {
                System.out.println("Attempting to create collection since non-existent...");

                DocumentCollection collectionDefinition = new DocumentCollection();
                collectionDefinition.setId(collectionId);

                PartitionKeyDefinition partitionKeyDefinition = new PartitionKeyDefinition();
                Collection<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
                paths.add("/id");
                partitionKeyDefinition.setPaths(paths);
                collectionDefinition.setPartitionKey(partitionKeyDefinition);

                RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
                options.setOfferThroughput(1000000);

                // create a collection
                client.createCollection(databaseLink, collectionDefinition, options);

                collectionResponse = client.readCollection(collectionLink, null);
                readCollection = collectionResponse.getResource();
            } else {
                throw dce;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(readCollection.getId());
        System.out.println(readDatabase.getId());

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("e:\\test.json")) {

            //Read JSON file
            Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);

            JSONArray jsonArray  = (JSONArray) obj;
            System.out.println(jsonArray);
            // cast jsonarry to string list
            if (jsonArray  != null) {
                int len = jsonArray.size();
                for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
                    list.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
                }
            }
            System.out.println(list.get(0));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Set client's retry options high for initialization
        client.getConnectionPolicy().getRetryOptions().setMaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds(30);
        client.getConnectionPolicy().getRetryOptions().setMaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests(9);

       // Builder pattern
        DocumentBulkExecutor.Builder bulkExecutorBuilder = DocumentBulkExecutor.builder().from(
                client,
                databaseId,
                collectionId,
                readCollection.getPartitionKey(),
                20000) ;// throughput you want to allocate for bulk import out of the container's total throughput

         // Instantiate DocumentBulkExecutor
        try {
            DocumentBulkExecutor bulkExecutor = bulkExecutorBuilder.build();
            // Set retries to 0 to pass complete control to bulk executor
            client.getConnectionPolicy().getRetryOptions().setMaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds(0);
            client.getConnectionPolicy().getRetryOptions().setMaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests(0);
            BulkImportResponse bulkImportResponse = bulkExecutor.importAll(list, false, false, null);
            System.out.println(bulkImportResponse.getNumberOfDocumentsImported());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204185/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-xu-bulk-upload-import-of-json-files-to-azure-cosmos).

Comment: I ran this code in a different environment and it runs perfectly fine. There are some issues in my env because of which I was facing errors.

Comment: Thank you for all the help @Jim-Xu.